# Right translate $\rho(f_n)\phi$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff unimodular topological group, and $\phi: G \rightarrow \mathbb C$ a continuous function.  For any continuous and compactly supported function $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb C$, define

$$\rho(f)\phi(x) = \int\limits_G \phi(xy)f(y)dy.$$

The integral converges absolutely, since $y \mapsto \phi(xy)f(y)$ is a continuous function vanishing off of a compact set.  Is $\rho(f)\phi$ actually a continuous function?

When $G$ is first countable, I can think of a very simple proof using the dominated convergence theorem.  I wondered if there is an easy way to prove this when $G$ is not necessarily first countable.

**Proof when $G$ is first countable**:

In this case, continuity can be checked on sequences, so it suffices to show that for any $x_0 \in G$ and sequence $x_n \to x_0$, that we have $\lim\limits_n \rho(f)\phi(x_n) = \rho(f)\phi(x)$.

Let $\Omega$ be a compact set containing the support of $f$, so that

$$\rho(f)\phi(x) = \int\limits_{\Omega} \phi(xy)f(y)dy.$$

If we define a function $h_n: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb C$ by $h_n(y) = \phi(x_ny)f(y)$, then there is a uniform bound $M$ on all the functions $h_n$ (since the $x_n$ and $y$ all belong to a compact set).  Then $h_n(y)$ converges pointwise to $\phi(x_0y)f(y)$, with $|h_n| \leq M 1_{\Omega}$.  The dominated convergence theorem implies that
$$\lim\limits_n \int\limits_{\Omega} h_n(y)dy = \lim\limits_n \rho(f)\phi(x_n) = \int\limits_{\Omega} \phi(x_0y)f(y)dy.$$